# JQuery Handling JSON or Array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hey guys, I'm having a problem handling my callback data in JQuery.
The following is my AJAX:

```
$(".ajaxPostMessage").submit(function() {

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $.post(action, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
    });

    return false;

});
```

My PHP goes something like..

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>1, 'msg'=>'message here'));
```

I can't seem to get the data.result or data.msg to print, I get 'undefined'. I'm wondering if I have to also pass the post as JSON? But that shouldn't matter.. I have also tried $.parseJSON but to no avail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
  $.post(action, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
    },'json');
```

This tells jQuery your returned data is json

Comment: Thanks this was the answer! I have to pass that json at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

`data` will be a string.

You can call `$.parseJSON` to parse it as JSON.

Comment: I had tried that, it appears the 'json' above was the answer, but thanks!